# Remove bottom border on last item in mmenu?

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

I am using the "mmenu" JQuery plugin (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/), which I have all set up and working as I want it to, except for one annoying point!

I want to remove the bottom border of the last menu item only.

All other styling and css to remain as it is.

I have tried adding:

```
border-bottom: none;

border: 0px;

border: 0px !important;
```

To the last < li > element, and also tried adding:

```
border-bottom: none;
```

To the top < ul > element, but the last bottom border always remains!

There seems to be an add-on css file on the mmenu website that allows you to remove or restyle all borders, but I only want to remove this one bottom border on only the last menu item, not on all menu items.

Any tips on how to get rid of this bottom border on just the very last menu item only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the border from the `:after` pseudo element on the last `li`

```
li:last-child:after  {
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: My last li item is just text, and doesnt contain an anchor tag.

Comment: my mistake, ive updated my answer... it's the pseudo

Comment: you may need to make the style `!important` to force the border style

Answer (score 0):

please share the structure of your menu so we can assist. There is pseudo that you can use to set styling only to the last child.The pseudo is :last-child.